# What should be first in modifiers order ? Mirror or skin ? How to avoid mirrored skin bugs?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

I am constantly confused by this. Every tutorial on Youtube seems to approach this problem differently. Combining Skin with Mirror always provokes endless amount of problems with my mesh - sometimes it becomes doubled and overlapping after applying all, other times it becomes deeply restructured around root vertex, or other times it visually looses symmetry despite mirror. Every time i get back to modelling after a little break I have to face these problems, please clarify it for me

Comment: the order depends on your object, I guess most of the time Mirror comes before Skin. Actually you must think as if you applied the modifiers, which one would you apply first to get the proper object, etc

Comment: Can You give some examples ? What would be benefit of having mirror after skin ? It bothers me, becasue most of mesh errors happen right after applying mirror

Comment: I don't know, maybe sometimes it's necessary, but I guess most of the time Mirror comes before  ;)

Comment: please share a file where you meet the problem you're talking about: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I think one advantage of using mirror after skin is that you can use the bisect option along the symmetry axis

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/6b0546478fe14473bf740e7ea7ad02fb

Comment: This is a good example. If You try to apply skin modifier You will notice mesh gets restructured slightly. And I have to apply skin first, as I want to work on base mesh in subdivided mode, apply it, and finally work on details on just mirror mode.